# Blazor WASM debugging in Rider

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly, rider

I am using the latest Rider version: 2023.1.1
.NET 6 Blazor Wasm application.

1. Enabled WASM debugging in the settings.
2. The line: app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging() is in the StartUp class.
3. The launchSettings are:

```
 "Blazor.Server": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001/;http://localhost:5000/"
},
```

Whatever I try I can't get the breakpoints to be hit in the UI.

What I found:
Breakpoints in the server actually get hit.
If I run the same application in VS the debugging works.
If I start with a new Blazor WASM template in Rider the debugging works.

I am not sure where could be the problem, has anybody experiences similar problems?

I would really like to use Rider, as I like the development experience.

Ideally, I would also like Hot Reload to work.